# Facebook comments Angular Directive in Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, facebook, ionic-framework

I'm using WordPress Api and have a simple directive for Facebook comments which receives the URL (i.e permalink) of the corresponding WordPress post. I have a list of posts that link to corresponding single post, the issue with the FB comments is that when I go into a single post the comments script dose not load. If I refresh the page, then the comments box displays correctly.

My question is how would I initiate the directive on the entering of a new single view? I have an idea about using a link, with a $watch, Im just not sure how to do it? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Facebook Directive:

```
.directive("facebookComments", function() {
return {
    scope: {
        commentsUrl: '=permalink'
    },
    template: '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{ commentsUrl }}" data-numposts="5"></div>'
}; });
```

HTML

```
<div facebook-comments permalink="post.url"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, all I had to do was add FB.XFBML.parse() to my $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() { FB.XFBML.parse();  })

Answer (score 0):

```js
.directive("facebookComments", function() {
return {
    scope: {
        commentsUrl: '=permalink'
    },
    template: '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{ commentsUrl }}" data-numposts="5"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('commentsUrl', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('newValue', newValue)  
      })
    }
}; });
```

I have added a link function to your directive which contains a watcher that will log to the console each time the url changes!

Good luck